# SQL - SUM UP Query with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I event don't know how to explain my problem so please be patient with me..

The SQL Query I have at the moment is:

```
SELECT Count(CATEGORY),  COUNT(INCIDENT_ID), CATEGORY,

ROUND(Count(CATEGORY) * 100 / (SELECT Count(*) 
                              FROM   incident_view 
                              WHERE 
( create_month = Month(Now() - 
                INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
AND ( create_year = Year( 
      Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
AND customer_company_name = "Company"
   ), 1) AS Percentage
FROM   incident_view 
WHERE  ( create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
 AND ( create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
AND customer_company_name = "Company"
GROUP BY CATEGORY
ORDER BY COUNT(INCIDENT_ID) DESC
limit 6, 1525125215;
```

My Database has 10 Categories and this Query retrieves the Categories with the 7-10 most Records.

If I use the Query i receive the 4 lowest records from the database...
But I want to retrieve the 4 lowest Record as one Record called "Other" which contains (SUM's) up all the data from the query.

Example (RESULT) at the moment:

```
 Count(Category) | Category | Percentage
    10               Cat1       5.0
     15              Cat2       3.0
    20               Cat 3      4.0
```

But i Want the result to look like :

```
Count(Category) | Category | Percentage
   45             Other       12.0
```

Is there anyway to achieve this result?

Would appreciate any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want another [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html). 
Without a SQLFiddle, I cannot test this, but it's something like:

```
Select Sum(category_count), 'other', sum(percentage) 
from (
SELECT Count(CATEGORY) as category_count,  COUNT(INCIDENT_ID), CATEGORY,

ROUND(Count(CATEGORY) * 100 / (SELECT Count(*) 
                              FROM   incident_view 
                              WHERE 
( create_month = Month(Now() - 
                INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
AND ( create_year = Year( 
      Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
AND customer_company_name = "Company"
   ), 1) AS Percentage
FROM   incident_view 
WHERE  ( create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
 AND ( create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
AND customer_company_name = "Company"
GROUP BY CATEGORY
ORDER BY COUNT(INCIDENT_ID) DESC
limit 6, 1525125215) as original_query;
```

Comment: Can you post a SQLFiddle?